# dapper .net mapping with duplicate model properties for splitOn

Tags: .net, mapping, duplicates, dapper

I have two Model with same property name as

```
Class Office<br>
{
   int Id;
   string Name;
   Location Location;
}

Class Location
{
   int Id;
   string Name;
}

sqlConnection.Query<Office, Location, Office>("query", (o, l) => {o.Location=l}, splitOn="Id,Id").ToList();
```

How can i make it work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

well, you just forget return your new object in delegate

```
(o, l) => {o.Location=l; return o;}
```

i.e. you should wrote:

```
sqlConnection.Query<Office, Location, Office>("query", (o, l) => {o.Location=l; return o;}, splitOn="Id,Id").ToList();
```